# Join multiple tables (Special condition)

Tags: mysql, join

I was trying to think of a logic to implement this `mysql` query but i couldn't think of anything or  find anything on the internet. My task is to `Join` two or more tables and return it's matching fields. BUT if there are three tables matching rows on two tables has to be displays also. Say I have these 3 tables,

```
Table1-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa  
2   |bbbb
3   |ccc
4   |dddd
4   |dddd
5   |eeee

Table2-
num |info
----------
2   |bbbb
3   |ccc
4   |dddd
5   |eeee

Table3-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa
2   |bbbb
6   |ffff
7   |gggg
```

I want to join these three tables and get a result as follows,

```
Result-
num |info   num |info   num |info
----------- ----------- ----------
1   |aaaaa  NULL|NULL   1   |aaaaa
2   |bbbb   2   |bbbb   2   |bbbb
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
4   |dddd   4   |dddd   NULL|NULL
4   |dddd   4   |dddd   NULL|NULL
5   |eeee   5   |eeee   NULL|NULL
```

I have this query which only shows that is on all three tables.

```
   SELECT a . * , b. * , c . *
   FROM tbl_1 a
   JOIN tbl_2 b ON a.num = b.num
   JOIN tbl_3 c ON a.num = c.num
   ORDER BY a.num, b.num
```

BUT what i want, is to display even if the value appears in two tables.

Thank you very much. if this was addressed before it would be great help in pointing me in the right direction :) thanks again

**TABLE STRUCTURE UPDATE**

```
Table1-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa  
2   |bbbb
3   |ccc
3   |ccc
4   |dddd

Table2-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa
3   |ccc
4   |dddd
5   |eeee
6   |ffff

Table3-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa
6   |ffff
2   |bbbb
```

in such a senario the record `6    |ffff` doesnt get displayd,

**DESIRED OUTPUT UPDATE**

the result i want to obtain is,

```
Result-
num |info   num |info   num |info
----------- ----------- ----------
1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa
2   |bbbb   NULL|NULL   2   |bbbb
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
4   |dddd   4   |dddd   NULL|NULL
NULL|NULL   6   |ffff   6   |ffff
```

Comment: you only want to show records from table1 which the `num` contains on either table2 or table3?

Comment: @JohnWoo  Thank you for the reply..i need every table to be taken into consideration if thats possible :)

Comment: check my answer below, it's base on your example and desired result

Comment: @Hasitha so please correct your desired result or the select, because your desired result contains 2 Columns and your select will output 6 columns. Your question is not clear

Comment: @SirRufo sorry for that confusion i will edit my question

Comment: @Hasitha nice update but what is with Table2 (5,eeee) should it be displayed in the result? Please don't confuse others, take your time, think about and after that and a cup of tea, post again

Comment: @SirRufo YEs i was thinking the same thing..i will post back :) this thing makes me crazy nw :D anyway thank you fot he replies, i will update the question again :)

Comment: @SirRufo I updated with the result i want :)

Comment: @Hasitha ... and i edited your question to get rid of confusing :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was resolved by @Andreas Wederbrand,

[Full join for 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061615/full-join-for-3-tables)

Implementing a `full join` was the solution for my query.

Hope it helps for anyone who comes across this issue :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT num, info FROM table2
            UNION
            SELECT num, info FROM table3
        ) b ON a.num = b.NUM
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc90/2)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.num numA, a.info infoA,
        b.num numB, b.info infoB,
        c.num numC, c.info infoC
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
           ON a.num = b.num
        LEFT JOIN table3 c
           ON a.num = c.num
ORDER BY a.num
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc90/4)

Comment: hey this is what i am looking for.. :) thank you very much ... if u can may i know how to display data from all three tables like `a.* b.* c*` please ? :) i tried adding aliases to other table as `b and c` and tried displaying but it didnt work :(

Comment: because `c` doesn't exists. can you update your desired result? it looks confusing :D

Comment: woww man...i ddnt think that was possible.i am kinda new to this..thank you very much :)

Comment: umm there is a small issue.. it doesnt work for this senario, il update in the question

Comment: @Hasitha if you were able to post a scenario with all conditions and the desired result out of that. remove last row in Table2 and the everyone could see, that last row in the result also should disappear (as far as i understand your question)

Comment: well the data i have in the actual table is not the same..so the issue is, i have two records in table 1 and the last record occurs in table 3 which is the 5th record in that table..but it doesnt get displayed :( can you please help.. the update 1 you gave is similar to what Arun Killu posted :)

Comment: @SirRufo I agree with you. The example provided can be interpreted by another solution.

Comment: @JohnWoo It should be solved by adding WHERE NOT ISNULL(b.num) or NOT ISNULL(c.num) to your query :o)

Comment: ummm no..it still gave the same result :( @JohnWoo

Comment: @Hasitha i have update the SQLFiddle demo from John and removed one row out of Table2, have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a95/6/0

Comment: @Hasitha but it will not fit, because of your last edit (and i edit your question, to get rid of confusing)

Comment: @SirRufo umm any luck in the code..the result of your solution is the same as JohnWoo :(

Comment: @Hasitha maybe you should clean your eyes, because there is one row less than in Johns query ... but as i told, it will not fit your needs

Comment: @SirRufo hmmm..thnks anyway for your help i will try to find a work around :)

Comment: May i know a full join would do any good?? i know only how to emulate a full join for two tables, how to do for three tables??

Comment: @SirRufo and JohnWoo am deleting this question so i can ask what i need clearly again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a . * , b. * , c . *
  FROM tbl_1 a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_2 b ON a.num = b.num
  LEFT JOIN tbl_3 c ON a.num = c.num
  ORDER BY a.num, b.num
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply, but this only solved a part of the question..which is it joins for the number of rows that is available in the table.if table 1 were to contain less rows than the other tables the result only would show up to the number of records that table 1 conains.. :( any work around? to display matching records in any table??

Comment: @Hasitha so what do you really want to do? why is `6 nd 7` not showing up on your desired result?

Comment: @JohnWoo   i am trying to correlate data :) so i need to consider data which is appearing in at least 2 tables :) that is why i need this method and finally i need to data of all correlating fields as a result :)

Comment: @Hasitha i think u are storing redundant info in multiple table.

Comment: well...these tables are pre-generated and data can be repeated in this scenario..:)