# Join multiple tables to display data of 3 tables or more

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables as follows,

```
Table1-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa  
2   |bbbb
3   |ccc
3   |ccc
4   |dddd

Table2-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa
3   |ccc
4   |dddd
5   |eeee
6   |ffff

Table3-
num |info
----------
1   |aaaaa
6   |ffff
2   |bbbb
```

the result i want to obtain is,

```
Result-
num |info   num |info   num |info
----------- ----------- ----------
1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa
2   |bbbb   NULL|NULL   2   |bbbb
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
4   |dddd   4   |dddd   NULL|NULL
NULL|NULL   6   |ffff   6   |ffff
```

**OR**

```
Result 2-
num |info   num |info   num |info
----------- ----------- ----------
1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa  1   |aaaaa
2   |bbbb   NULL|NULL   2   |bbbb
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
3   |ccc    3   |ccc    NULL|NULL
4   |dddd   4   |dddd   NULL|NULL
NULL|NULL   5   |eeee   NULL|NULL
NULL|NULL   6   |ffff   6   |ffff
```

If there is a way to retrieve either one of the given results would be great :)
Thank you very much :) .. i tried using a full join like so,

```
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_1 AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 AS b ON a.num = b.num
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_1 AS a
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_2 AS b ON a.num = b.num
```

But its good for only 2 tables, if full join is the solution how to perform this?? if not how can i derive the result i want from the given three tables??

I tried searching but none helped to perform this task.

and i asked the question [Join multiple tables (Special condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043595/join-multiple-tables-special-condition/) but it didnt help..thought it might be unclear thats why i posted again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was resolved by @Andreas Wederbrand,

[Full join for 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061615/full-join-for-3-tables)

Implementing a `full join` was the solution for my query.

Hope it helps for anyone who comes across this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I think as posted in your earlier question below should work well:-

```
  SELECT  a.num numA, a.info infoA,
    b.num numB, b.info infoB,
    c.num numC, c.info infoC
 FROM    table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b
       ON a.num = b.num
    LEFT JOIN table3 c
       ON a.num = c.num
 ORDER BY a.num
```

Comment: well, it works, but when table 1 doesnt have a field it doesnt get displayed,,for example in my question record `6   |ffff` is not there in table 1..but i want that to be displayed in the result. :) n thanx for the reply

Comment: if you dont mind can you show me how to perform this :) am kinda new to this thank you